# change the bordercolor of UIPopOverController

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to change the default black like color of the UIPopOver to some another color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its default behavior we cant change it

Comment: yup, actually i forgot to answer myself. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer was wrong.. see this http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/customizing-the-design-of-uipopovercontroller