# How to change border color of UIPopoverController?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize / style a UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552686/how-to-customize-style-a-uipopovercontroller)

I need to change the border color of UIPopover controller?. By default it is dark blue. If anybody know please answer.

Comment: Further possible duplicates: [Remove border for UIPopoverController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710436/remove-border-for-uipopovercontroller) and [change the bordercolor of UIPopOverController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399861/change-the-bordercolor-of-uipopovercontroller).