# create a popover programatically without border

Tags: ios6, uipopovercontroller

I need to create a popover Programatically like the image showed below
 [image: photo]

The Problem I'm facing is while creating the popover it comes with default border.
is there any way to create the Popover without border.

Comment: have you ever considered about creating an own view...?

Comment: @holex I tried it by creating an own view but it's not working.

Comment: that is very interesting, because I've created one of these borderless popup for my own for one our clients' app, and there was zero problem with it... it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to remove the popover border. You can try something suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710436/remove-border-for-uipopovercontroller)