# How to set the popoverController border color

Tags: iphone, uipopover

Does anyone know if it is possible to customize the UIPopover border colour?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to customize / style a UIPopoverController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552686/how-to-customize-style-a-uipopovercontroller), [change the bordercolor of UIPopoverController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399861/change-the-bordercolor-of-uipopovercontroller).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. 
Apple doesn't support customization of the look of UIPopoverController.

If you want something different, you have to create your own from scratch.